# Powerapps, ThisItem.Field not working when trying to use SendEmailV2

Tags: power-automate, powerapp

I am trying to use the following line:

`Office365Outlook.SendEmailV2(DataCardValue2.Selected.Value,"Change Request-" & ThisItem.ID & ": " & ThisItem.Control,`

However the email being sent is not picking up the ID or control field.
How can I fix this statement to pick these up properly?

Thanks.

Comment: Where did you write this code, inside gallery or any other place where `ThisItem` is accessible?

Comment: @GaneshSanap its inside a button OnSelect,  that is inside the EditForm1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ThisItem` object is not accessible in EditForm and if you're not getting any errors that means it's referring to some other control being used.

There could be multiple ways to achieve this functionality -

1. If you're editing the item selected from the gallery list from other screen then you can use `GalleryName.Selected.ID` for accessing ID and so on.
2. On the Edit screen `OnVisible`, you can write store the list item in a local variable like `UpdateContext({ListItem: GalleryName.Selected})` or globally you can store your variable whenever you're getting it from data source.
3. You can have additional fields in the Edit form like ID and can make their height, width set as 0. In that way, you can access the ID by `DataCardValue.Text`
4. You can use the `EditForm.LastSubmit.ID` to get the item ID but I'm not 100% sure it'll work.